# In Shiny/R app - why plotly charts are flickering?

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

I having a trouble here, this is my code:

```
library(gapminder)
library(shiny)

library(plotly)
library(shinyWidgets)

df_first_mexico <- gapminder %>% filter(country == "Mexico")%>% select(year,lifeExp)
df_second_mexico <- gapminder %>% filter(country == "Mexico")%>% select(year,pop)
df_third_mexico <- gapminder %>% filter(country == "Mexico")%>% select(year,gdpPercap)

df_first_chile <- gapminder %>% filter(country == "Chile")%>% select(year,lifeExp)
df_second_chile <- gapminder %>% filter(country == "Chile")%>% select(year,pop)
df_third_chile <- gapminder %>% filter(country == "Chile")%>% select(year,gdpPercap)

ui <- fluidPage(

  mainPanel(

    tabPanel("Tab1",
             tabsetPanel(
               div(

                 pickerInput(
                   inputId = "inputs",
                   multiple = FALSE,
                   # width = "150px",
                   label = "Taxas - Sem Ajuste Sazonal",
                   choices = c("first",
                               "second", "third"),

                   selected = c("first"),

                   options = list(title = "Choice")
                 )
               ),
               tabPanel("SubPanelA",
                        div(
                          plotlyOutput("plot_A", width = "200px")

                        )
               ),

               tabPanel("SubPanelB",
                        div(
                          plotlyOutput("plot_B", width = "200px")

                        )
               )


))))




server <- function(input, output) {

  inputs_reactive <- reactive({input$inputs}) %>% bindCache(input$inputs)

  output$plot_A <- renderPlotly({

    if(inputs_reactive() == "first"){

    ggplotly(ggplot(df_first_mexico , aes(x = year, y = lifeExp)) + geom_line())

    }else{

      if(inputs_reactive() == "second"){

        ggplotly(ggplot(df_second_mexico , aes(x = year, y = pop)) + geom_line())

      }else{

        ggplotly(ggplot(df_third_mexico , aes(x = year, y = gdpPercap)) + geom_line())

      }


    }



  })

  output$plot_B <- renderPlotly({

    if(inputs_reactive() == "first"){

      ggplotly(ggplot(df_first_chile, aes(x = year, y = lifeExp)) + geom_line(color = "red"))

    }else{

      if(inputs_reactive() == "second"){

        ggplotly(ggplot(df_second_chile, aes(x = year, y = pop)) + geom_line(color = "red"))

      }else{

        ggplotly(ggplot(df_third_chile, aes(x = year, y = gdpPercap)) + geom_line(color = "red"))

      }


    }



  })




  }

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

My question is: why when I select different tabpanels and change the inputs happens this flickering effect (**is it the right name?**) on the `ggplotly()` charts ?

For example:

suppose that I choose the "first" option. Then I click on SubPanel B and choose "second" option. And then I click on the SubPanel A and the flickering happens. Why?

I also tried to use `bindcache(input$inputs)` but I have this error message: `Don't know how to handle object with class plotly, htmlwidget`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "issue" is that for efficiency, Shiny by default won't update outputs that aren't visible. When you're on the second tab and change the input, the `plot_B` updates but `plot_A` doesn't. When you click back to the first tab, you're browser still has the previous plot rendered. Now being visible, Shiny realizes this is out of date, and switches to the new plot causing the "flicker."

It's easy enough to solve, just be careful overriding the default behavior with outputs that take a long time to calculate. After you define your outputs in the server, add these lines:

```
  outputOptions(output, "plot_A", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
  outputOptions(output, "plot_B", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
```

Comment: amazing your help. thanks for your time. LAst question why `bindCache()`doesnt work with `ggplotly`? I have this message: `Error in bindCache.default: Don't know how to handle object with class plotly, htmlwidget`

Comment: This is a separate issue from the flicker. It's hard to know without seeing the context where your calling it. `bindCache` expects a reactive element as it's first argument so from the error message I would take that an object of class `plotly` is somehow being passed in. That being said, I would not expect `bindCache(input$inputs)` to actually provide any benefits. The caching is being done on the server side, where all the inputs are being sent as values from the client side. For the inputs, there are no values to calculate hence no time to be saved.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is: why when I select different tabpanels and change the
> inputs happens this flickering effect **(is it the right name?)**

Incase this steers you - I think searching for issues with memory leak problems in the shiny library might help you delve further (rather than describing it as a 'flickering effect').

For example: 
https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1591

https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/2321