# Shiny Plotly Plot Flickering With Module Input Changes

Tags: r, shiny, module, plotly

I have the following app. When I deselect all items from level1 and then reselect them there is a rapid flickering until level4 stabilizes. This makes sense as updates to level 4 should update the graph, but I'd like to 'freeze' the output until the sequence is complete.

I've tried `outputOptions(output, "plot", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72914630/in-shiny-r-app-why-plotly-charts-are-flickering), `tags$style(type="text/css", ".recalculating {opacity: 1.0;}")` from [here](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1591), and wrapping my renderUI's in `isolate`.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

# sample data

x <- tibble(level1 = c(rep("A", 100), rep("B", 100), rep("C", 100), rep("D", 100)),
            level2 = c(rep("A1", 50), rep("A2", 50), rep("B1", 50), rep("B2", 50),
                       rep("C1", 50), rep("C2", 50), rep("D1", 50), rep("D2", 50)),
            level3 = c(rep("A21", 25), rep("A22", 25), rep("A23", 25), rep("A24", 25),
                       rep("B21", 25), rep("B22", 25), rep("B23", 25), rep("B24", 25),
                       rep("C21", 25), rep("C22", 25), rep("C23", 25), rep("C24", 25),
                       rep("D21", 25), rep("D22", 25), rep("D23", 25), rep("D24", 25)),
            level4 = c(rep("A31", 10), rep("A32", 10), rep("A33", 10), rep("A34", 10), rep("A35", 10),
                       rep("A36", 10), rep("A37", 10), rep("A38", 10), rep("A39", 10), rep("A310", 10),
                       rep("B31", 10), rep("B32", 10), rep("B33", 10), rep("B34", 10), rep("B35", 10),
                       rep("B36", 10), rep("B37", 10), rep("B38", 10), rep("B39", 10), rep("B310", 10),
                       rep("C31", 10), rep("C32", 10), rep("C33", 10), rep("C34", 10), rep("C35", 10),
                       rep("C36", 10), rep("C37", 10), rep("C38", 10), rep("C39", 10), rep("C310", 10),
                       rep("D31", 10), rep("D32", 10), rep("D33", 10), rep("D34", 10), rep("D35", 10),
                       rep("D36", 10), rep("D37", 10), rep("D38", 10), rep("D39", 10), rep("D310", 10)))

y <- x %>%
  mutate(value = runif(400, 0, 100))

# modules

orgHierarchyUI <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tagList(
    uiOutput(ns("level1")),
    uiOutput(ns("level2")),
    uiOutput(ns("level3")),
    uiOutput(ns("level4"))
  )
}

orgHierarchyServer <- function(id, data){
  
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session){
      
      output$level1 <- renderUI({
        ns <- session$ns
        cs <- data %>%
          distinct(level1) %>%
          arrange(level1) %>%
          pull(level1)
        pickerInput(ns("level1_select"), label = "Level 1", choices = cs, selected = cs, multiple = TRUE, options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE))
      })
      
      output$level2 <- renderUI({
        ns <- session$ns
        cs <- data %>% 
          filter(level1 %in% input$level1_select) %>%
          distinct(level2) %>%
          arrange(level2) %>%
          pull(level2)
        pickerInput(ns("level2_select"), label = "Level 2", choices = cs, selected = cs, multiple = TRUE, options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE))
      })
      
      output$level3 <- renderUI({
        ns <- session$ns
        cs <- data %>%
          filter(level1 %in% input$level1_select) %>%
          filter(level2 %in% input$level2_select) %>%
          distinct(level3) %>% 
          arrange(level3) %>%
          pull(level3)
        pickerInput(ns("level3_select"), label = "Level 3", choices = cs, selected = cs, multiple = TRUE, options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE))
      })
      
      output$level4 <- renderUI({
        ns <- session$ns
        cs <- data %>%
          filter(level1 %in% input$level1_select) %>%
          filter(level2 %in% input$level2_select) %>%
          filter(level3 %in% input$level3_select) %>%
          distinct(level4) %>% 
          arrange(level4) %>%
          pull(level4)
        pickerInput(ns("level4_select"), label = "Level 4", choices = cs, selected = cs, multiple = TRUE, options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE))
      })
      
      return(list(
        level1_select = reactive({input$level1_select}),
        level2_select = reactive({input$level2_select}),
        level3_select = reactive({input$level3_select}),
        level4_select = reactive({input$level4_select})
      ))
    }
  )
}
# ui, server, app

ui <- fluidPage(
  orgHierarchyUI("hierarchy"),
  plotlyOutput("plot") %>% withSpinner()
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  hierarchy <- orgHierarchyServer("hierarchy", data = x)
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    req(hierarchy$level4_select())
    y <- y %>% 
      filter(level1 %in% hierarchy$level1_select()) %>%
      filter(level2 %in% hierarchy$level2_select()) %>%
      filter(level3 %in% hierarchy$level3_select()) %>%
      filter(level4 %in% hierarchy$level4_select()) %>%
      mutate(value = round(value,-1))
    y %>% plot_ly(x = ~value, type = "histogram")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I'd recommend using `updatePickerInput` instead of `renderUI`. Furthermore you might want to check `?pickerGroupUI()`.

Comment: Yes, but in (this case) selectizeGroupUI/selectizeGroupServer doesn't have the option to have a drop-down with a select all/deselect all feature, does it?

Comment: Well, the information I wanted to provide you with is that using `updatePickerInput` will stop the "flickering" (might need to be combined with `freezeReactiveValue`), as it updates an existing UI element instead of re-rendering it (`renderUI`). This procedere is also used by shinyWidgets' `pickerGroup-module` - so I thought you might want to have a look at the code. The select all/deselect all feature is not needed to understand this concept - however, for sure it could be implemented.

Comment: `freezeReactiveValue` is exactly what I thought I needed, but I'm struggling to understand its implementation and there isn't a ton of examples of it. I also don't see it in the `pickerGroup-module` source code. Any chance you could mockup an answer using `freezeReactiveValue` and `updatePickerInput` using the example above while keeping its module structure?

Comment: As the `pickerGroup-module` already does 95% of the job I'd recommend to file a [feature request](https://github.com/dreamRs/shinyWidgets/issues).